# U-Boot - Embedded Linux - Terminal Connection

Tags: linux, serial-port, u-boot

I have an embedded linux board with a max3222e RS232 converter. The pins are availlable on soldering pins. I think I've figured out the ground pin, the TX pin and the RX pin. When I connect my pc with a terminal program, I can see the boot logs of the embedde linux system. Also I can stop u-boot with pressing any key. But when I try to use some boot arguments then the characters of the pressed key are not the same like on the pc. For example:

Enter->y

a -> 0

s -> F

Can anybody tell me what's wrong. The serial settings are 115200 Baut 8N1 and no Flowcontrol.

Thanks a lot

Karl-Heinz

Answer (score 0):

What terminal you use ? I use minicom. I have set

```
`NO PROGRAMING FLOW CONTROL,'

`YES DEVICE FLOW CONTROL`.
```

And u-boot char is send good.
You try other terminal for example putty for windows ?